# Entity Framework adds Default value by itself

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

i have the following table definition (trimmed):

```
CREATE TABLE `mt_user` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dtUpdated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idUpdatedBy` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dtCreated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idCreatedBy` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

As you can see, no default value was assigned to `idUpdatedBy` and `idCreatedBy`.

When trying to insert a row from workbench, it fails (since i do not provide `idCreatedBy` or `idUpdatedBy`).
Which is the correct behaviour.

On the other hand, if i use a simple form to insert using Entity Framework, the fields are populated with a `0` value, even though i have not defined a default value (neither in entity framework).

i was expecting Entity Framework to fail the insert and throw an error about `idUpdatedBy`/`idCreatedBy` not having a value.

Could someone explain this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: Int is not nullable with a default value of 0. When you create an object with int properties in C#, they are all defaulted to 0.

Comment: Can that behaviour be changed? why would EF behave differently then the db?

Comment: Entity Framework tries to couple C#'s language capabilites to the relational db model as well as possible. However, an EF entity created in code doesn't inherently "know" that it's a db entity, wherefor `idUpdateBy` and `idCreatedBy` are set to 0 as to C#'s default behaviour. As to "fixing" this behaviour: it's working exactly as intended. If you want to work around this, you'll have to do so in code. You could attempt to make the default values of these properties illegal to provoke a different exception (not recommended) or you could do a value check before inserting new entities.

Comment: does it makes sense to have a trigger before update on the db to check for 0 value and assign null? that way i will get the expected behaviour i was looking for.

Comment: That sounds like a super ugly solution to a not so ugly problem. Can you elaborate on why you need exactly this behaviour? And maybe make an example of what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i have a webAPI and i would like to log the changes on some records. allowing .NET to populate the fields mentioned above with 0 values is illegal (since i do not have any user with that id). i am very surprised by this behaviour. could have fooled me with "Default Value" being null but sending 0's

Comment: Well, the way I see it with the info you've provided, those should be foreign keys on the user table. If your table structure was correct, you'd eliminate these kind of invalid entries through the implicit "error checking" on invalid foreign key constraints.

Comment: darn it, you're right. i only started the db design and forgot the constraints.....